# Find all hashtags in string using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I'm having problems figuring out the right regex pattern for the search `preg_match_all("THIS PART", $my_string)`. I need to find all hashtags in my string with the word after the hashtag included as well.

So, these strings should be found by the mentioned function:

**Input**

```
#hi im like typing text right here hihih #asdasdasdasd #
```

**Result**

```
#hi
#asasdasdasdasd
```

**Input**

```
#asd#asd xd so fun lol #lol
```

**Result**

`#asd#asd2` would be two seperate matches and `#lol` would be matched aswell.

I hope the question made sense and thanks beforehand!

Comment: What have you tried yet? There is not much that is easier to do with Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
/#(?<hash>[^\s#]+)/g
```

It searches for **#** and creates then a named group called *hash*, it stops matching after it reaches another **#** or after any whitespace character (\s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match_all

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!\w)#\w+/', $your_string, $allMatches);
```

It will give all contain # tag word. hope it help you.

```
print_r($allMatches)
```